# I just start my journey in Flutter App development. And I wanted to create dynamic dashboard using Stack and InkWell

Tags: flutter

**I just start my journey in Flutter App development. And I wanted to create dynamic dashboard using Stack and InkWell :**

Thank You in Advance ..

I also wanted to bring info from the database in order to specify the services that my app provide. And the services should be coming from the database in the future or in couple of days from now, if I got lucky.

**Here is my Code ..**

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    InkWell _catogo(BuildContext context, page, txt) {
      return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => page));
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            child: Container(
              height: 85,
              width: 85,
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                '$txt',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              )),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: size.height * 0.4,
          child: Stack(
            overflow: Overflow.visible,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: size.height * 0.3,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Mcolor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(36),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(36),
                    )),
              ),
              Positioned(
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                top: 80,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    // child: catoItems(),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Wrap(children: [
                        _catogo(context, Page1(), 'Page1'),
                        _catogo(context, Page2(), 'Page2'),
                        _catogo(context, Page3(), 'Page3'),
                        _catogo(context, Page4(), 'Page4'),
                        _catogo(context, Page5(), 'Page5'),
                        _catogo(context, Page6(), 'Page6'),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

> #the problem is Inkwell won't get Tabbed inside the stack ..

Answer (score 0):

> ## It worked with me when I change **Positioned()** With **Align()** :

Here :

```
 Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      // child: catoItems(),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Wrap(children: [
                       _catogo(context, Page1(), 'Page1'),
                        _catogo(context, Page2(), 'Page2'),
                        _catogo(context, Page3(), 'Page3'),
                        _catogo(context, Page4(), 'Page4'),
                        _catogo(context, Page5(), 'Page5'),
                        _catogo(context, Page6(), 'Page6'),
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

> ## If you Found better soluation Can You please Provided to me .. Thanks.